# How can I convert from a CSV file to scala toList?

Tags: scala, csv

How can i convert from a CSV file to a list in Scala, when the rows of data have a date and a int, and are separated by different lines. This is about a stock market.

The function below takes a stock symbol and a year as arguments.
 It should read the corresponding CSV-file and then extract the January 
data from the given year. The data should be collected in a list of
strings (one entry for each line in the CSV-file).

```
def get_january_data(symbol: String, year: Int) : List[String] = {
}
```

The csv file is like this:

```
Data          AJD  
12/01/1998    0.32232  
14/01/1998    0.32232
```

12/01/1998,0.32232,14/01/1998,0.32232

Comment: Please provide a few lines of sample input (file content) and desired results.

Comment: Date Adj Close
02/01/1981 0.49263
05/01/1981 0.481921
06/01/1981 0.460502
07/01/1981 0.440868
08/01/1981 0.431944

Comment: and the desired result would be a List[String] (one entry for each line in the CSV-file).

Comment: sorry question is edited

Comment: Is there not a simple way of getting information from a csv?

Comment: CSV stands for Comma Separated Values. I don't see any commas.

Comment: if they were separated by commas, how would to appoach it

Comment: I'm guessing that the `AJD` in your sample is an example of `symbol:String`, and that this and other symbols are scattered throughout the file, and you want the January data lines for a given year but only those under a specified symbol. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you can start with following piece of code:

```scala
    val data =
        """Data          AJD
          |12/01/1998    0.32232
          |14/01/1998    0.32232
          |14/02/1998    0.12333
          |01/01/1999    0.12333""".stripMargin


      def getJanuaryData(symbol: String, year: Int): List[String] = {
        val dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
        val xs: Vector[(LocalDateTime, Double)] = fromString(data, dtf)
        xs.filter(x => (x._1.getMonthValue == 1) && x._1.getYear == year)
          .map(x => s"${x._1.format(dtf)}  ${x._2}").toList
      }

      def fromString(str: String, dateFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")): Vector[(LocalDateTime, Double)] = {
        str.split("\n").tail.map { line =>
          val tokens = line.split("    ") // consider different separator
          (LocalDate.parse(tokens(0), dateFormatter).atStartOfDay()
            , tokens.tail.head.toDouble)
        }.toVector
      }
      getJanuaryData("", 1998)
```

`getJanuaryData()` return rows for january and required year. Please add more information about stock symbol to get precise answer.